# Difficulty importing JWT (JSON Web Token) in Spring Boot Gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a Spring Boot gradle project and in the build.gradle dependencies, I import JSON Web Token as:

```
compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.2'
```

Following Spring Security and a video tutorial, I have then built out a successful Authentication method. However, when I use Jwts in this method, it does not prompt me to import the same file as in the video tutorial and in fact does not have a prompt for any import options. Specifically, in the video (which uses Maven), the prompt is added to import:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken
```

Yet in my app I am never given this option and importing this manually or as import io.jsonwebtoken.*; does not work. As the class indicates that:

```
import io cannot be resolved
```

Similarly, the SignatureAlgorithm method does not contain an import from JWT.

How can I successfully import JSON web token into my gradle project (or at least import io). The method from the video tutorial is below. Jwts is the implementation of the web token and it is the package I am having difficulty with.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                HttpServletResponse res, 
                FilterChain chain, 
                Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();

    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userName)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_SECRET)
            .compact();

    res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
}
```

The project itself I am putting together is on Github and the above noted class is at:

https://github.com/jwolfe890/SpringBootProject1/blob/master/src/main/java/sbootproject/security/AuthenticationFilter.java

Comment: do you have your project in github?

Comment: yes, this is the class I am talking about https://github.com/jwolfe890/SpringBootProject1/blob/master/src/main/java/sbootproject/security/AuthenticationFilter.java

Comment: @Dog, Please check and merge, I did changes required in your project: https://github.com/jwolfe890/SpringBootProject1/pull/1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I got your problem you should use 0.2 instead of 0.2.0

For gradle 4.10 it would be good to use implementation instead of compile.

```
implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.2')
```

[image]

Comment: That didn't work either. I initially had it as .2 but changed it when I was trying different versions. I think it might have something to do with the build path but cleaning it and re-starting Spring Tool Suite hasn't worked.

Comment: it works for me with `compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.2'` or `implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.2')`. try to do `./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: now it's telling me "Error: Could not find or load main class sbootproject.SBootJpaProject1Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sbootproject.SBootJpaProject1Application"

Comment: do you know why it would say that?

Comment: yes. it doesn't make sense because the classes are laid out the same as before.

Comment: your github project has compile error, userDetail should remove exception thrown. also what did you do to get above error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185341/discussion-between-dog-and-chi-dov).

Answer (score 1):

Following errors I observed from your github project repo:
1. need to add `import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;` in AuthenticationFilter.java
2. UserService.java has method `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws Exception;` which is similar to `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;` in `UserDetailsService` interface, I removed since both serves same purpose
3. Updated method `loadUserByUsernam`e in `UserServiceImpl.java` and throws `UsernameNotFoundException` exception instead of `Exception`(since the method is derived from `UserDetailsService` interface)

I raised merge request to your repo and changes are: https://github.com/jwolfe890/SpringBootProject1/pull/1/files

Do let me know if this is not what you expected.

Comment: for some reason this issue was unique to Spring Tool Suite. After merging your changes and switching to Intellij it worked.

Comment: It should work after merging my changes (which are mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

It here worked - Reference - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.2

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

If your application to maven, then insert in **pom.xml** file

[image]

Comment: For modern users, using version `0.2` no longer works and will cause the import error, but you can find the most recent version by following the maven links on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For others seeking answer when JWT token dependency not getting imported: it seems like a bug in IntelliJ.
Add the dependency to another project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to add these dependencies successfully to the maven project in IntelliJ IDE.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: it did not work for me, unfortunately =(

Answer (score 0):

I ran below command inside project folder

```
gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

and added below line in gradle file

```
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
```

and it worked for me . thanks.